# Переконвертировать дату в MySql timestamp

Tags: php

Дата приходит с формы таким форматом.

```
[Date] => 16/02/2017 [Time] => 14:25
```

Приходит Post Запросом. Эту дату нужно записать в БД Mysql. Формат поля timestamp

Вот такой:

```
2017-02-22 02:00:00
```

Как привести к такому типу с помощью PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$date = ['date' => '16/02/2017', 'time' => '14:25'];

$date = new DateTime(str_replace('/', '.', $date['date'].' '.$date['time']));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Класс **[Datetime](http://php.net/manual/ru/datetime.format.php)** в доках

А чтобы не писать `str_replace`, то можно воспользоваться методом **[createFromFormat](http://php.net/manual/ru/datetime.createfromformat.php)**,  который разбирает строку, содержащую время, в соответствии с заданным форматом

Answer (score 0):

Можно с использованием регулярки:

```
preg_replace('/(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{4})/', '$3-$2-$1', $post['Date'])." ".$post['Time'].":00";
```

Answer (score 0):

Давно есть нативный класс `Datetime`, которых может проверить формат и форматировать дату как угодно.

```
$Date = \Datetime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i', $request['Date'] . ' ' . $request['Time']);
if (! $Date) {
    // дата в неверном формате
}
echo $Date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```